# How to access database table not mapped as entity class

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

I want to access all records of my database table in spring + hibernate. I am using MySql as a database. The scenario is I cannot map this table to entity class, as this table is created run time (dynamically).
I tried to access by the Query "`SELECT * FROM tableName`" but I received the error: 
 `org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: * near line 1, column 8 [SELECT * FROM tableName].`
And when I tried "`from tableName`" I am getting mapping related errors. If it is a silly question then please provide me some links from where I can get information regarding this. 
Please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible in HQL but hibernate allows to fire native SQL.

You can use

```
SQLQuery nativeQuery=session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM tableName");
List results=nativeQuery.list();
```

And check the list. Or add Entity to map the results using `nativeQuery.addEntity(YourEntityClassHere.class)`